# How to test Login API NodeJs using Mocha and Chai

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js, chai

I am new to Test driven development and I want to test my login API but I cant seem to understand fully how to implement tests with Database and what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: I am using express with sequelize ( CLI ) as an ORM.

Comment: Oops, sorry for unclear question. I mean, what kind of web framework are you using?

Comment: @winter I am using Node JS if that's what you are asking.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not what i'm asking. What I'm asking is are you using any kind of web framework? Like express for example. Or are you just using the built-in node.js http module?

Comment: I have already said I am using Express framework and apart from that I have installed Mocha and chai.

Comment: Oh my, i am sorry. I didn't see that comment. Okay then i'll try to answer your question. However, i have never used sequelize. So my answer will be based on my experience.

Comment: sure, I am unsure what is the best practice and how to get the grip of it while starting.

Answer (score 6):

First, I am also not an expert in this topic but i have been using this method for quite some time. If anyone find that what i'm writing is wrong or somewhat misleading, please correct me. I am very open to critics and opinions.

As the name suggests, TDD method requires you to write the test before the implementation. Basically, you write the test, see it's failing, write the implementation and repeat until the test is passed.

If you are using express, you may want to use the `supertest` module. They way to use it is similar to `superagent`. You can install it by running

```
npm install supertest --save-dev
```

I am going to show you a very simple example of how to use it with mocha and chai.

So here's an example of express app:

```
// file: app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// your middlewares setup goes here

const server = app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('Server is listening on port 8000');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And here's the example test case of the login API:

```
// file: test/api.js
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Login API', function() {
    it('Should success if credential is valid', function(done) {
        request(app)
           .post('/api/v1/login')
           .set('Accept', 'application/json')
           .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
           .send({ username: 'username', password: 'password' })
           .expect(200)
           .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
           .expect(function(response) {
              expect(response.body).not.to.be.empty;
              expect(response.body).to.be.an('object');
           })
           .end(done);
    }); 
});
```

You may run it with this command

```
node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test/**/*.js
```

The example above assumes that you will implement the login API using POST method at /api/v1/login path. It also assumes that you will receive and respond data with json format.

What the example test case does that it tries to send a POST request to /api/v1/login with the following data:

```
{
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
}
```

Then, it expects that your API will respond with 200 response code as shown in this line:

```
.expect(200)
```

If it receive a response with code other than 200, the test will fail.

Then, it expect that the `Content-Type` of your response to be `application/json`. If the expectation does not meet the reality, the test will also fail.

This code below:

```
.expect(function(response) {
  expect(response.body).not.to.be.empty;
  expect(response.body).to.be.an('object');
})
```

It checks the response from your server. You can use the chai's `expect` inside the function body as shown above. You may notice that supertest also provide `expect` method. But, the way to use both supertest's expect and chai's expect is different.

And finally, call `end` function with `done` callback so that the test case can be run properly.

You may want to check supertest documentation to get more details on how to use it.

**Establishing database connection before testing**

If you need to maintain a database connection before running all the test case, here's the idea:

Create another file inside the `test` directory. For example, `database_helper.js`. Then, write the following code:

```
before(function(done) {
    // write database connection code here
    // call done when the connection is established
});
```

I've tried it with mongoose before, and it worked for me.

I hope that helps.

Comment: to add some thoughts: i ususally initialize the database with a certain data before each test. You can use ```beforeEach(function(done){});``` for that.

Comment: i am facing below error                                                                                                           https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/17821101_1469610449726804_1117021897_n.png?oh=0faa94eb2e5a915d27ab03017eda40e2&oe=58EADD80

Comment: @RizwanPatel I can not open the link, but i edited the answer. I didn't noticed the error, thanks!